# В случайное время очищаются данные из таблицы в БД MSSQL

Tags: c#, .net, sql-server, asp.net

Есть огромное приложение на asp.net, оно работает с БД MSSQL где есть таблица с названием UserGroup. В случайное время(раз в месяц) может произойти очистка таблицы UserGroup полностью, чего в приложении не предусмотренно. Никакие хранимки, функции и тд не выполняют таких функций. Как костыль, могу повесить тригер на таблицу, что бы отключить удаление, но это на крайний случай. Как можно отследить откуда приходит запрос и исправить ошибку?

Comment: бывший сотрудник шалит?)

Comment: Создайте пользователя БД с привелгиями исключая DELETE. Дальше используйте только что созданную учётку в ASP NET.

Comment: @OYBEKRUSTAMOV к сожалению должен остаться способ удаления через приложение по 1 значению, а в данном случае удаляются почему то все и сразу

Comment: `должен остаться способ удаления через приложение по 1 значению, а в данном случае удаляются почему то все и сразу` - вероятно где-то запрос на удаление без `WHERE`

Comment: @Bulson да, это скорее всего, но найти сложно. Нашел способ через тригер, можно вызвать исключение в приложении через него, попробую так отловить хотя бы контроллер который вызывает такое поведение

Comment: По-хорошему, `DELETE` должна быть запрещена на рабочей БД совсем. Нужно использовать только софт-удаление через значение бит.поля `IsDeleted`. Удаление из таблиц, нарушает индексы, уничтожает историю пользования БД, чего быть не должно.

Comment: Вам уже подсказали, создайте пользователя с запретом на удаление, работайте через него. Когда-то и где-то у кого-то не получится удаление, и таким образом найдете запрос где это происходит.

Comment: @Bulson в данном случае удаляются данные которые являются привелегиями для определенного рода задач, в приложении и доступа к чему либо, плодить множество данных с такими значениями не разумно. В данном случае не я разрабатывал, так что изменить нет возможности точно(

Comment: @Bulson в БД множество таблиц из которых можно удалять данные, запрет на всё я думаю будет не разумно, вроде запрет на удаление из одной таблицы я не видел такой функции

Answer (score 1):

Есть несколько вариантов.

1. Написать руками триггер на таблицу:

```
CREATE TRIGGER trg_dbo_UserGroup_d
ON dbo.UserGroup
AFTER DELETE
AS
BEGIN
    INSERT INTO dbo.Audit ([Time], UserName, HostName, AppName)
    SELECT GETDATE(), ORIGINAL_LOGIN(), HOST_NAME(), APP_NAME()
END
```

2. Воспользоваться аудитом БД. Подробное описание можно найти [тут](https://www.sqlshack.com/various-techniques-to-audit-sql-server-databases/).