# Поиск того что вызвало удаление в базе через NHibernate listener

Tags: c#, sql, .net, asp.net-mvc, nhibernate

В данный момент у меня случайным образом удаляются данные из БД, хочу отследить из какого метода прилетает удаление. Создал Listener который бы отслеживал события OnPreDelete с проверкой на данные модели.

```
if (@event.Entity is IProcessHeaderAccess)
{

}
```

Можно ли в @event где то увидеть откуда прилетел запрос на удаление?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/1103916/222542 вы все бьетесь с этой проблемой? Запустите поиск по всему проекту на слово `DELETE`, проверьте все эти запросы на правильность. Задайте вопрос с тегом `sql` чтоб спецы по базам могли покумекать, может у вас какая-то конфигурация БД с недостаточными размерами под лог файлы или сам файл БД.

Comment: @Bulson да, всё над ним. По всему проекту уже искал, но все равно он слишком большой, может что-то и пропустил

Comment: Не знаю насчёт слушателей событий, но в NHibernate вроде можно с помощью перехватчиков (Interceptor) получать выполняемые sql-запросы. Если даже там нет возможности получить имя метода, откуда пришёл запрос, то можно в интерсепторе проверять, есть ли в запросе слово `delete` и банально выбрасывать исключение (и тут же его ловить) и по stack-трейсу смотреть уровнем выше.

Comment: Я малость глупость написал про выброс исключения. Это не нужно. Достаточно создать экземпляр [StackTrace](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.diagnostics.stacktrace?view=netframework-4.8). А делать это, вероятно, следует в [OnDelete](https://nhibernate.info/doc/nhibernate-reference/events.html)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Interceptor к сожалению я не смог запустить, именно по этой статье. Работают только события